# OpenGL - Getting camera to move

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, glm-math

I'm having trouble with my OpenGL game where I can't get the camera to move.

I am unable to use GLFW, GLUT and glulookat(). Here is my code, what's wrong?

P.S everything works except the camera movement meaning the game plays and works perfectly, just cant move the camera.

My Camera Code:

```
    #include "SpriteRenderer.h"

    #include <glm/glm.hpp>
    #include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>

    class Camera
{
private:
    Shader shader;

    GLfloat     angle = -90.f;

    glm::vec3   cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),
                cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f),
                cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    glm::mat4   viewMatrix;

    // recompute the view matrix from the camera variables
    void updateMatrix()
    {
        viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + cameraFront, cameraUp);
    }

    // default constructor
    void defaultNew()
    {
        cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f);
        cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
        cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        updateMatrix();
    }

public:
    Camera() { defaultNew(); }
    Camera(Shader &shader) { this->shader = shader; defaultNew(); }

    glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix() const
    {
        // if your view matrix is always up-to-date, just return it directly
        return viewMatrix;
    }

    // get functions
    glm::vec3 GetCameraPosition() const { return cameraPosition; }
    // .. same for Front and Up

    // set functions
    // call updateMatrix every time you update a variable
    void SetCameraPosition(glm::vec3 pos)
    {
        cameraPosition = pos;
        updateMatrix();
    }
    // .. same for Front and Up

    // no need to use this-> all the time
    virtual void Draw()
    {
        this->shader.Use();
        this->shader.SetMatrix4("view", viewMatrix);    
    }
};
```

My Shader Code:

```
Shader &Use(){ glUseProgram(this->ID); return *this; }

void SetMatrix4(const GLchar *name, const glm::mat4 &matrix, GLboolean useShader = false)
    { if (useShader)this->Use(); glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(this->ID, name), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(matrix)); }
```

My Game Code:

```
Camera *View;

projection2 = glm::perspective(glm::radians(44.0f), (float)this->Width / (float)this->Width, 0.1f, 100.0f);

AssetController::LoadShader("../src/Shaders/Light.vert", "../src/Shaders/Light.frag", "light");

AssetController::GetShader("light").SetMatrix4("projection", projection2);

View = new Camera(AssetController::GetShader("light"));
```

(...)

```
GLfloat velocity = playerSpeed * deltaTime;
glm::vec3 camPosition;

// Update Players Position
if (movingLeft)
{
    if (Player->Position.x >= 0)
    {
        Player->Position.x -= velocity;
        if (Ball->Stuck)
            Ball->Position.x -= velocity;

        camPosition = View->GetCameraPosition();
        camPosition.x -= velocity / 2;
        View->SetCameraPosition(camPosition);
    }
}
else if (movingRight)
{
    if (Player->Position.x <= this->Width - Player->Size.x)
    {
        Player->Position.x += velocity;
        if (Ball->Stuck)
            Ball->Position.x += velocity;

        camPosition = View->GetCameraPosition();
        camPosition.x += velocity / 2;
        View->SetCameraPosition(camPosition);
    }
}
```

(...)

```
GameOver->Draw(*Renderer);
    View->Draw();
```

My Shaders:
.vert:

```
#version 440 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;

out vec2 TexCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0f);
    TexCoord = vec2(aTexCoord.x, aTexCoord.y);
}
```

.frag:

```
#version 440 core
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoord;

// texture samplers
uniform sampler2D texture1;
uniform sampler2D texture2;

void main()
{
    // linearly interpolate between both textures (80% container, 20% awesomeface)
    FragColor = mix(texture(texture1, TexCoord), texture(texture2, TexCoord), 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you only update local position variable `cameraPosition`, and not the *view matrix*, which is passed to OpenGL during rendering.

It is also a bad habit to make the camera variables and matrix public, as they can potentially be modified incorrectly or *out-of-sync* (as you are doing). Instead, you could write a pair of `get/set` functions:

```
class Camera
{
private:
   Shader shader;

   GLfloat     angle = -90.f;

   glm::vec3   cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f),
               cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.1f),
               cameraUp = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

   glm::mat4   viewMatrix;

   // recompute the view matrix from the camera variables
   void updateMatrix()
   {
      viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + cameraFront, cameraUp);
   }

   // default constructor
   void defaultNew()
   {
      cameraPosition = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f,  0.1f);
      cameraFront    = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
      cameraUp       = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f);
      updateMatrix();
   }

public:
   Camera() { 
      defaultNew();
   }
   Camera(Shader &shader) { 
      this->shader = shader;
      defaultNew();  
   }

   glm::mat4 GetViewMatrix() const
   {
      // if your view matrix is always up-to-date, just return it directly
      return viewMatrix;
   }

   // get functions
   glm::vec3 GetCameraPosition() const { return cameraPosition; }
   // .. same for Front and Up

   // set functions
   // call updateMatrix every time you update a variable
   void SetCameraPosition(glm::vec3 p)
   {
      cameraPosition = p;
      updateMatrix();
   }
   // .. same for Front and Up

   // no need to use this-> all the time
   virtual void Draw()
   {
      shader.Use();
      shader.SetMatrix4("view", viewMatrix);
   }
};
```

And then when you update the camera position, simply use these functions instead of the exposed variables:

```
view->SetCameraPosition(view->GetCameraPosition() + velocity / 2.0f);
```

This will make sure that the draw calls always use the updated view matrix instead of the initial one (which was the case before and the source of your troubles).

Comment: @ChrisRoss can you show your updated code? Also, does it make a difference if you call `SetMatrix4` *before* `Use()`?

Comment: @ChrisRoss just curious: if you were to pass some different view matrices to your shader, would it have any effect?

Comment: at this point I don't think theres much we can do to help you, based on the current code sample; can you add a link to a repository with your *full* code? (don't post the code itself here)

Comment: I'm a little out of ideas; just trying to get SDL working so that I can run the code and debug it (hopefully)

Comment: Don't think enabling depth is relevant to this problem, but still necessary for 3d rendering with solid polygons

Comment: I located a possible source of error in your **unshown** code: in `Game::render` you call `View->Draw()` last. You should always call it *before* rendering any 3D content. Also, in your main game loop you should also clear the depth buffer by adding this flag: `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);`. Neither of these line were in the code you provided, which just goes to show that you should always provide a link to your entire repository (but not paste directly).

Comment: You've only uploaded 4 headers btw. Also, you might want to check the output of `glError`.

Comment: I can't see any code files at all for some reason; only the Shaders and Levels folders.

Comment: Have you had any luck?

Comment: Having finally got it to compile with SDL, it only displays a blank screen.

Comment: I use Visual Studio Community 2017. I could try conan/cmake but I have no experience with conan; and in the past cmake has been a huge pain on Windows.